# Does stage Sy of instruction have to wait till all earlier instructions has executed their corresponding stage

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, mips, processor

I am trying to understand execution of instruction in [RISC pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline).

Can stage Sy of instruction I2 execute before stage Sy of I1? That is, in below example, will it be allowed to run I2's ID in C3 as ID stage is free in C3, or it has to wait till I1's ID is executed, that is, it can execute only in C5?

[image]

I assuming multiple stage buffers which allsows I2's IF occur in C2 even when I1 is stalled in C2.

Column Cx stands for clock cycle x.
Row Ix stands for instruction x.
IF is instruction fetch stage.
ID is instruction decode stage.
EX is execute stage.
Dashes in cell indicated stalls. This may be because I1's ID stage depends on some input from earlier instruction (not shown in table.)

Comment: Do you have a bit more context for your question?

Comment: Exactly what more information is needed? Just added a wikipedia link.